# Internet quota management

Tags: internet, quota

We currently have a very limited download limit with a few users on our LAN. Is it possible to set either daily or monthly limits for each user and to throttle them when they go over. I have briefly looked into using something like this [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/index) but am unsure if it has what I am after. What other methods are possible, the most cost effective and user friendly.

Comment: See this,...http://markmaunder.com/2011/01/26/how-to-reliably-limit-the-amount-of-bandwidth-your-room-mate-or-bad-office-colleague-uses/

Comment: This is great for bandwidth limiting but I'm also after data limiting, defiantly put me on the right track. Maybe it could be done by scripting.

Comment: That or a taser gun for those data hogs.

Comment: I'm afraid I would have to tase myself..

Answer (score 0):

Worked this out building a pfSense box using the captive portal and free radius although still having trouble with the scripting part, at the moment it just kicks the user off if they go over their limit. The alternative is that you could have 2 logins one for when your within your limit and one thats capped when you go over but this could get very annoying when you have multiple devices.

http://www.pfsense.org/